# If statement inside For loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use this code in Excel to get a product color from column AW and then replace the value in column J with the SKU for that product color.  It works, except it pastes the formula in column AY for EVERY row, instead of just the rows where the column J value is "WCblack", so that causes it to run pretty slowly.

Any ideas how I can get it to only put the formula in rows where column J value is "WCblack"?  Thanks!

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, "J").Value = "WCblack" Then
            Range("AY2:AY" & lastRow).Formula = "=TRIM(LEFT(AW2,FIND(CHAR(10),AW2)-1))"
                If Cells(i, "AY").Value = "Color: Red" Then
                    Cells(i, "J").Value = "WCred"
                ElseIf Cells(i, "AY").Value = "Color: Gold" Then
                    Cells(i, "J").Value = "WCgold"
                ElseIf Cells(i, "AY").Value = "Color: Blue" Then
                    Cells(i, "J").Value = "WCblue"
                End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Since you are referencing `Cells(i, "AY").Value` over and over, and that slows things down, consider using a `Select Case` instead of several `If` statements.

Comment: `Range("AY2:AY" & lastRow).Formula = "=TRIM(LEFT(AW2,FIND(CHAR(10),AW2)-1))"` needs to be outside of the loop. A clue would be that it does not use the loop variable `i` and it applies to all rows under `"AY"`.

Comment: That is part of the code that I only want to be put in the rows where column J is "WCblack", so wouldn't it have to be in the loop?  I have tried `Range("AYi:AY" & lastRow).Formula = "=TRIM(LEFT(AWi,FIND(CHAR(10),AWi)-1))` to use the loop variable, but I can't get it to work correctly.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use `VLOOKUP()` in excel to read of a table of color codes?